# How to change system language?

Tags: gnome, language-support

I use Ubuntu-Gnome 13.04 and I can't change system language.
I set it to Polish with "language & regions".
It was though because there is no option for adding so i installed:

language-pack-pl

language-pack-gnome-pl

then i could pick it in "language & regions" and then reboot.
However this didn't solve my problem 
I also change it with gnome-language-selector and still got english.

Please help, because if the language is other than polish i will have to switch back to windows.
I like the gnome3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obviously the language support tools are still incomplete in Ubuntu GNOME.  Desktop Help states the following:

> Select your desired language. If your language is not listed click `:` at the bottom of the list to select from all available regions or languages.

Only after selecting a language there clicking on <kbd>Done</kbd> has no effect.

To have the language selection back in the form it is installed in other releases we have to install [language-selector-gnome](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/language-selector-gnome) [image: Install language-selector-gnome]. After we did so, we will have an additional icon *"Language Support"* in our *System Settings* from where we can install any supported language by choosing *"Install/Remove Languages"*:

[image]

Drag the interesting language to the top of the list. Select *"Apply System Wide"* to also have this language at log in, and system wide.

Comment: This is the solution in general I think so I mark it as the solution. But in my case I had to uninstall all languages I had (language-pack-pl, language-pack-gnome-pl, language-pack-en, language-pack-gnome-en). Then install both en(language-pack-en, language-pack-gnome-en), then reboot and install both pl (language-pack-pl, language-pack-gnome-pl).

Comment: There is no "Apply System-Wide" in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.  I am stuck and consider editing some configs manually.

Comment: @Alexey: did you do `sudo apt install language-selector-gnome`? Only with this application the new *Language Support* can be selected as shown above. I just tested this on 17.04 Ubuntu GNOME, it is still valid.

Comment: Thanks, @Takkat, i have now a new settings panel.  However, what is weird is that i somehow switched the system language to French before (i believe, using the ordinary user language panel) but was not able to switch it back to English.  I have already switched it back by editing `/etc/default/locale`.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question right, you want to change everything to polish.  If that's the case then, add the language first, and Apply system wide.

[image]

Do the same for Regional Format

[image]

And add the keyboard layout.

[image]

[image]

Then you will get the language icon which allows you to switch between keyboard layouts.

[image]

Comment: I try this exactly but language will not set into Turkish.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the language at the login prompt after selecting the user. When asked whether to make the selection the new default, select yes