# Unable to change language

Tags: gnome, 13.04, language-support

I have just installed [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) 13.04. I'm trying to change the language (System Settings => Region & Language), but only English is available and there is no way to add an another language in list.

[image: I don't have enough reputation]

I suppose there is an another way, and I need help :).

Comment: Does this help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language Support is the easiest tool for adding languages. Do you see a Language Support icon in the System Settings menu? If not, you can do

```
sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome
```

After that you should be able to add the desired language(s) using Language Support.