# Change the system folder name back to English

Tags: language-support

There are some system folders in Ubuntu including documents, download, etc.

The operating system language on my computer is Chinese and those folder names are also displayed in Chinese, like the name of folder "document" is 文档, which is document in Chinese.

May I ask how to change them back to English?

Many thanks.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/289225/202806

Comment: He only wants to change the folder names, not the system language

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open a Terminal and run

```
LANG=C xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

Log out and log in again to apply the new configuration.

This will just configure and create the new folders but not touch your old folders or copy any files. You have to move the files from the old folders to the news ones yourself.