# i cant update 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: updates, 14.04

i try to update my os today 13.10 to 14.04 and i have this error

> Third party sources disabled
>
> Some listings have disabled third file souces.list. You can activate after the upgrade tool with the 'software-properties' or with your package manager.
>
> Απενεργοποιήθηκαν πηγές τρίτων
>
> Μερικές καταχωρίσεις τρίτων έχουν απενεργοποιηθεί στο αρχείο souces.list. Μπορείτε να τις ενεργοποιήσετε μετά την αναβάθμιση με το εργαλείο 'software-properties' ή με τον διαχειριστή πακέτων σας.

and

> We could not calculate the upgrade
>
> A non-solvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This can be caused by:
>   * Upgrading to a demo version of Ubuntu
>   * The use of the current trial version of Ubuntu
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu.
>
> If you apply any of that, then please report this error by using a terminal command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'.
>
> Αδυναμία υπολογισμού της αναβάθμισης
>
> Ένα μη επιλύσιμο πρόβλημα συνέβη κατά τον υπολογισμό της αναβάθμισης.
>
> Αυτό μπορεί να προκλήθηκε από:
>   * Την αναβάθμιση σε μια δοκιμαστική έκδοση του Ubuntu
>   * Τη χρήση της τρέχουσας δοκιμαστικής έκδοσης του Ubuntu
>   * Ανεπίσημα πακέτα λογισμικού που δεν παρέχονται από το Ubuntu.
>
> Αν δεν ισχύει τίποτα από αυτά, τότε παρακαλούμε αναφέρετε αυτό το σφάλμα χρησιμοποιώντας σε ένα τερματικό την εντολή 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'.

and how i can install ubuntu to my phone?

Comment: English only, please.

Comment: Are you using Software Updater?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to change the language settings of your OS to English (temporarily), then try to upgrade and post the error messages? See [How to change system language?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed one/some PPAs that are not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.

Uncomment the entries in sources.list and do a proper

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:'name'
```

or

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:'name'
```

(substitute **'name'** by the PPAs name!).

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo autoremove --purge
```

after that you should be able to update to 14.04.

If that fails: do a clean install of 14.04 (and try to avoid PPAs if you are planing to upgrade) ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu for Phones is available only for Google Nexus devices, officially. That too the unstable beta version. I will not be responsible for any loss of data or damage to your phone, whether you use a Nexus or not.**

Follow this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install