# How can I change Calendar's Language and adjust Time and its Format?

Tags: language-support, clock

Language on calender is not english and time is wrong and 24hr format.I dont know how to change it.I selected Georgia as my state but on map it showed maybe USSR ?

Comment: Hello. Please try any of the workarounds mentioned in the answers to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language and let us know if you succeed or yet experience the same symptoms. It will be useful if you edit your question in order to add the details of what you have already tried and its results in order to receive further support. Additionally please let us know which version of Ubuntu have you installed. Welcome and Good luck!

Comment: Georgia is [not just one of the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_%28country%29).

Answer (score 2):

Besides what PKumar suggested, open *System Settings -> Language Support*, switch to the *Regional Formats* tab, and select **English (United States)**.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command below and select the region you want to

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: This sets the timezone, not the language

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on the calendar and selecting either "Set date and time" or "Change settings for calendar" or something similar and then adjusting to the right timezone and right date and time format?

It's not really clear which calendar application you're using, but when I right click on my clock/calendar these options appear.