# How can I enable the Irish language for the desktop on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, language-support, system-settings

I have run the Language Support tool and clicked Install/Remove Languages... and installed Irish. I can see from the Ubuntu Software Center that at least two packages are installed *-ga-base being one of them.

But Irish still doesn't appear on the list in the Language Support tool. Apparently, when I installed the language, there is supposed to be a + for more options, which is missing (and is a bug). (See the accepted answer here [How to change system language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language) for more details)

How can I get languages other than just English on the list in Language Support?

**Update**: Running gnome-language-selector from the terminal I see this output:

```
gnome-language-selector:22702): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-iIuzZfldLm: Connection refused
[]
[<Package: name:'firefox-locale-ga' architecture='amd64' id:2712>, <Package: name:'language-pack-ga-base' architecture='amd64' id:2713>, <Package: name:'language-pack-gnome-ga-base' architecture='amd64' id:5653>, <Package: name:'language-pack-gnome-ga' architecture='amd64' id:5651>, <Package: name:'myspell-ga' architecture='amd64' id:1918>, <Package: name:'libreoffice-l10n-ga' architecture='amd64' id:11807>, <Package: name:'kde-l10n-ga' architecture='amd64' id:33666>, <Package: name:'language-pack-ga' architecture='amd64' id:5649>]
```

Other output:

```
$ /usr/share/language-tools/language-options 

en  en_AU  en_CA  en_GB  en_NZ  en_US
```

Output of locale -a:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Running sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-pack-ga-base

```
Setting up language-pack-ga-base (1:14.04+20150804) ...
Generating locales...
  ga_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

And subsequently (I may have been ssh'd into the wrong machine first time!)

```
Generating locales...
  ga_IE.UTF-8... cannot open locale definition file `ga_IE': No such file   or directory
failed
Generation complete.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you refer to is about Ubuntu GNOME, but since you have Ubuntu, there is no "+" to look for.

As I mentioned in a [reply to the bug comment you wrote](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/657488/comments/4), thie Irish option is labeled "Gaeilge" in the list.

*Edit:*

Please run these commands:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/ga
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

That ought to bring Gaeilge in.

*Edit II:*

Okay, the Gaeilge locale has apparently not been generated. As a next measure, I suggest that you run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-pack-ga-base
```

If that succeeds, you may want to try this again:

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

*Edit III:*

The failure when generating locales indicates that the locales package was incompletely installed. So let's redo that:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

Comment: Gaeilge is listed in Language Support, not the Install/Remove dialog. And only if it has been successfully installed. First you must select 'Irish' from the Install/Remove Languages section. I am not getting Gaeilge on this machine though. I've added the console output to my original question. Hopefully it's revealing - and not beacuse I was ussing X forwarding from another machine.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Let's find out the status: Can you please run `/usr/share/language-tools/language-options` and let us know the output. Also, does the command `check-language-support` result in any output?

Comment: Thanks Gunnar. The second command returns nothing, but the first shows output. Question updated again :)

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Ok, the problem you are having with installing via Language Support is over my head - something with dbus. But I edited my answer with a couple of suggested commands.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Did those commands solve the problem?

Comment: The mkdir command wasn't necessary as the dir was already there. The second command doesn't install anything because check-language-support returns nothing. I'm stumped as to why this would be the case on one machine and not another.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Can you please show us the output of the command `locale -a`

Comment: Okay, I've just updated the original post @Gunnar.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Only English locales. :( I edited my answer again ("Edit II") with suggested next steps.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence @Gunnar :) The first command yields the output I've added to the first post. The check-language-support still returns nothing on it's own or paired with apt-get install.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Ok.. "up-to-date" was unexpected. Is the ga_IR locale possibly included now when you run `locale -a`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But for reference, my other 14.04 machine has ga_IE.utf8
included in the results for that command. Edit: See my updated command. There is a failure reconfiguring the language pack now. It's possible I was ssh'd into the wrong machine when I ran it first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30511/discussion-between-tenleftfingers-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Comment: Your suggestion to run sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales fixed my issue, thank you. I'll accept the answer if you can add that to it.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: Done. Glad that we figured out the cause finally. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Gunnar. I really appreciate your persistence! :)