# Can I have one user language in Polish and keep the sudoer's account (mine) in English?

Tags: login, users, language-support, ubuntu-studio

Can I have one user language in Polish and keep English for me when I log in?

If so, how do I go about installing Polish language for Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: I have found this tar gz file >> https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=language-pack-pl

Comment: Last I checked, Ubuntu studio used XFCE, same as Xubuntu, There is "Language Support" in the menu, just add Polish, then logout, select Polish at the login screen, and login as the desired user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change system language?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289190/how-to-change-system-language)

Answer (score 2):

There is "Language Support" in the menu, just add Polish, then logout, select Polish at the login screen, and login as the desired user.

[image]